# Get the xaml root where userControl is

Tags: c#, reflection, winrt-xaml

Using Reflection in c# (winRt) , is possible to get dynamically the root of the page in which my userControl belongs to?

#### UserControl xaml

```
  <SearchBox PlaceholderText="{Binding placeholder,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   Width="300"
                   Margin="20,0,20,0"                   
                   SearchHistoryEnabled="False"
                   FocusOnKeyboardInput="False"
                   ChooseSuggestionOnEnter="True"
                   SuggestionsRequested="SearchBoxSuggestions"
                   ResultSuggestionChosen="SuggestionChoosen"
                   QueryChanged="SearchQueryChanged"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   x:Name="searchBox"
                />
```

#### UserControl Code behind

```
    public void SuggestionChoosen(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox sender, SearchBoxResultSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(args.Tag);
        TransporterExt t = new TransporterExt();
        t = suggested[p];
        selected = t;

        //I WANT TO GET HERE THE ROOT OF THE PAGE IN WHICH USER CONTROLLER BELONGS TO
    }
```

How can I get the root of the page from the codeBehind of my UserControl?

Comment: Did you give it a try? What didn't work?

Comment: there is absolutely no need for such a thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to "set" some field of xaml of the page that include my userControl, from my userControl...  i got a searchbox inside my userControl, after a choose (in uc) i want to initialize the fields of the page, and i need only the root of the page in wich uc belongs to, but, from the codebehind of my uc, i don't know how i can i get it

Comment: Show the markup and the code...

Comment: And where is the problem? Did you read [ask]? Please trim down the code to the part that is relevant to your question.

Comment: `i want to "set" some field` - create a proper data model and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: That is much better and I'm sure answerable...

Comment: btw. you construct the `t` just to assign it a new value in the next line - you need to work on your C#/WPF a bit. As for the question, no need as others said, just pure 'data binding', look up the ListBox SelectedItem data binding examples, that's what you have pretty much

Comment: @NSGaga yes, the code now is very dirt... can u explain better how can i bind it?

Comment: hmm, you need to focus a bit, do something - e.g. you are 'event driven' as I see, don't expose events, that's an old win-forms style. Expose instead the 'SelectedSuggestion' which is a 'value' (property) - and then you'd bind to it like `{Binding SelectedSuggestion}` but you need to wire the data context to view-model and all that. I suggest you take up some basic ListBox SelectedItem binding examples, you started from the end, you need to learn the basics